# Sendgrid API throwing a CORS error during test

Tags: php, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

Good afternoon, everyone! I am getting a CORS error when attempting to test Sendgrid in PHP. Here is my setup:

I have a Vue based from end which calls a vanilla PHP api for some basic tasks. Both the front end and API sit on an Amazon Lightsail server. In one of those PHP files I put the sendgrid test. NOTE: This api is truly vanilla, and I setup the sendgrid files manually since there is no composer file. Here is the error I get when the send grid functionality is called:

```
Array
(
    [0] => HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
    [1] => Server: nginx
    [2] => Date: Fri, 04 Dec 2020 16:51:19 GMT
    [3] => Content-Length: 0
    [4] => Connection: keep-alive
    [5] => X-Message-Id: X8jfBPyWS8eU0jhW5qWJrQ
    [6] => Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://sendgrid.api-docs.io
    [7] => Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
    [8] => Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl
    [9] => Access-Control-Max-Age: 600
    [10] => X-No-CORS-Reason: https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html
    [11] => 
    [12] => 
)
```

Yes, I read the cors link provided, but I don't think it applies to my situation. Here is the relevant PHP:

```
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_STRICT);
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
include_once '../lib/sendgrid-php/sendgrid-php.php';
```

After this comes other code that doesn't factor into the SendGrid aspect, so I won't clutter the page by posting it. Below is where the sendgrid part of the file executes:

```
$apiKey = "myapikey";
$email = new \SendGrid\Mail\Mail();
$email->setFrom("REALEMAIL", "Alert");
$email->setSubject("Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun");
$email->addTo("TESTRECEIPTEMAIL", "MY NAME");
$email->addContent("text/plain", "and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP");
$email->addContent("text/html", "<strong>and easy to do anywhere, even with PHP</strong>");
$sendgrid = new \SendGrid($apiKey);

try {
  $response = $sendgrid->send($email);
  print $response->statusCode() . "\n";
  print_r($response->headers());
  print $response->body() . "\n";
} catch (Exception $e) {
  echo 'Caught exception: '. $e->getMessage() ."\n";
}
```

To address obvious points first: TESTRECEIPTEMAIL and REALEMAIL are valid emails in the actual code and the API key referenced IS a valid api key. And no, I do not plan on leaving the API key just sitting in the file, like I said, all I'm trying to do at the moment is to get sendgrid to work first.

Any insight into this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: "I  am getting a CORS error" — Exactly what is the error message? CORS is only relevant to JS and you haven't included any of that in your question (aside from a passing mention of Vue). Test your PHP with a stand alone REST client. Does it work? Then worry about getting it to work with JS. If you get an error then, then debug the JS and *your* PHP. Forget about SendGrid's end.

Comment: I should have been more specific: I copy/pasted the error as I simply have the PHP api dump it to the console.

I did run this test using only a direct call to the API, not originating from the JS front end and get the exact same 202 error as shown above.

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer may be simply my complete blindness to the code responses. It looks as though it actually IS accepting the response, but the emails are never going out, which is an entirely different problem. Ugh, my apologies to all for wasting time.